# Are Twilightsworn considered Lightsworn?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What is the official ruling for [Twilightsworn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Twilightsworn) cards? Are they considered [Lightsworn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsworn)?

For example, using [Judgement Dragon](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Judgment_Dragon), would Twilightsworn can be used as one of the "Four Lightsworn in the graveyard"? I've searched the web, but I haven't found a definite answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes they are also considered [Lightsworn](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsworn) cards**.

The key part is to notice that "Twigh**lightsworn**" also contains the word "Lightsworn" on its name, so they are also considered part of the Lightsworn archetype.

Another case are the [Tellarknight](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tellarknight) achetype, which include cards with "Sa**tellarknight**" or "S**tellarknight**" on their names. Example cards that belong to this archetype are [Tellarknight Ptolemaeus](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Tellarknight_Ptolemaeus), [Satellarknigth Vega](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Satellarknight_Vega), and [Stellarknight Triverr](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Stellarknight_Triverr).

Other strange cases are cards like [Darktellarknight Batlamyus](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Darktellarknight_Batlamyus) (also Tellarknight archetype), and [Satellarknight Zefrathuban](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Satellarknight_Zefrathuban) (which is both Tellarknight and [Zefra](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Zefra) archetypes).

---

In case this was not convincing, there is another reference from the Yugioh Wikia that [states](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Twilightsworn):

> "Twilightsworn", known as "Twilightlord" (トワイライトロード Towairaitorōdo) in the OCG, is a series of DARK monsters introduced in Code of the Duelist, **and a sub-series of the "Lightsworn" archetype**.

Furthermore, if we compare the Japanese names of both we can see they share a same root which enables them to belong to the same archetype.

Lightsworn or "Lightlord" in the OCG is spelled "**ライトロード Raitorōdo**", and Twilightsworn or "Twilightlord" is spelled "トワイ**ライトロード** Towai**raitorōdo**".

This is similar to the case of the [Archfiend](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Archfiend) archetype, which due to translation from Japanese, includes now all cards that in their OCG names include the "Daemon" character (**デーモン**).

This means that cards like [Summoned Skull](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Summoned_Skull), which OCG name is **デーモン**の召喚 (Summoned Daemon, translated), *are part of the Archfiend archetype*.

Comment: Do you have any other credible sources? Thank you though for the answer. Just one problem: I asked my friend few hours ago, (who wouldn't lie to me about Yu-Gi-Oh ruling) said that where he found it, "Twilightsworn" wasn't considered Lightsworn. Now I'm really confused!

Comment: @North not to be rude but your friend is wrong. Perhaps he is not lying, but ignores such thing. I'll try to find a more official source, although the Yugioh Wikia which I linked is pretty thorough and correct, to set this matter straight :)

Comment: @North another argument and example I can think of is the Archfiend archetype. Surely you have seen some cards of those. The interesting thing is that other cards like Summoned Skull *are* part of the Archfiend Archetype, as they derive from the Japanese Names which included the "Daemon" character. Thus, any card that has such character was later retroactively classified as Archfiend card (like Axe of Despair for example). More info [here](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Archfiend), if it helped I can include it to the answer

Comment: The most credible source is "Lumina, Twilightsworn Shaman"s effect: Once per turn: You can banish 1 "Lightsworn" monster from your hand or GY, then target 1 of your banished "Lightsworn" monsters, except "Lumina, Twilightsworn Shaman"; Special Summon it. Once per turn, if your other "Lightsworn" monster's effect is activated: Send the top 3 cards of your Deck to the GY.
Why would she need to mention herself, if she would not be considered "Lightsworn"?

Comment: @pascalpuetz exactly, that is also evidence that they are the same archetype