# What is the criteria for being a "X" monster?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I have a monster X (none in particular), and a card says with Y (again, none in particular) in its name. What is the criteria for monster X being a part of name Y?

For example, [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/40500/19332) asks whether a Twilightsworn is considered a Lightsworn monster. The answer is yes, but how is this known? Is it solely because there is "Lightsworn" in "Twilightsworn" ?

Other examples include Dracoslayer in Draco Slayer_____.

Comment: Maybe this is my lack of knowledge of the game showing, but this question makes absolutely no sense to me. Can you include an example of what X and Y might be?

Comment: We'll be able to give a much better answer if you provide a specific example. The wording of your question is quite vague, at the moment.

Comment: VortexYT, as others have already said it isn't real clear what you are asking right now, and as it stand your question is likely to be put on hold. It would be really helpful if you could add a specific example, even if  you want to question or answers to be generic, so that people can clue into more about what for an answer.

Comment: The edit clears up the question nicely, hopefully the close-voters will stop by to retract their votes. @CDClarke do you find the edit acceptable?

Comment: I think that [my answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/40505/22373) over there already explains *"how is this known?"*: Originated from the OCG (Japanese), if a card contains in it's name certain prefix or sub-word it is considered of that Archetype... archetypes are the key concept here, and in that answer you can see a detailed explanation and example with some archetypes.

Comment: Edit makes it clear, but now it's a dupe of the question DarkCygnus linked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Twilightsworn considered Lightsworn?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40500/are-twilightsworn-considered-lightsworn)

Comment: @DarkCygnus How is it a duplicate?

Comment: @VortexYT because what you ask I already answered over there IMO (and also in the opinion of other 4 users). Do you think my answer over there could be improved or clarified?